# Contador JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

tengo problemas para el contador que he realizado en JavaScript cuando pulso el botón. He intentado varias soluciones, pero no sé porqué el contador no me lo hace bien.

```js
let botones = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
let valor = document.querySelector("#valor");
let contador = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {

  botones[i].addEventListener("click", () => {

    if (botones[i].classList.contains("disminuir")) {

      console.log(valor.innerText = contador--);

    } else if (botones[i].classList.contains("incrementar")) {

      console.log(valor.innerText = contador++);


    } else {

      console.log(valor.innerText = 0);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <article id="contenedor_principal">
      <h1>Contador</h1>
      <p id="valor">0</p>
      <div id="botones"> <button class="btn disminuir" type="button">Disminuir</button> <button class="btn resetear" type="button">Resetear</button> <button class="btn incrementar" type="button">Incrementar</button> </div>
    </article>
  </main>
  <script src="./contador.js"></script>
</body>
```

Un saludo y gracias!!!

Comment: <body>
    <main>
        <article id="contenedor_principal">

            <h1>Contador</h1>
            <p id="valor">0</p>

            <div id="botones">
                <button class="btn disminuir" type="button">Disminuir</button>
                <button class="btn resetear" type="button">Resetear</button>
                <button class="btn incrementar" type="button">Incrementar</button>
            </div>

        </article>
    </main>
    <script src="./contador.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: Te he editado la pregunta porque as puesto el html en un comentario.

Comment: Si, porque me decía que no me dejaba poner tanto código en la publicación

Comment: Para estos casos tienes que tomar la opción de añadir el código con el snippet apropiado. Te he editado la pregunta y ahora verás que incluso se puede verificar tu código con un simple click

Comment: si no dices el comportamiento esperado y su diferencia con el comportamiento actual, la verdad es que "no lo hace bien" suena a que tenemos que interpretar más que ayudarte a debuggear

Comment: @ffflabs "no me lo hace bien" lo he escrito como diciendo que no entiendo porque no me lo hace bien, yo sólo he lanzado una pregunta, si tú quieres respondes o no, pero no tienes por qué responder con esa sobradez. No todos somos unos Pros como tú y hay gente que necesita aprender y el saber porqué de las cosas. Saludos!!

Comment: No te pongas a la defensiva, solamente ten en cuenta que si nos dices: "quiero que haga A y hace B" vas a tener mejores y más prontas respuestas que si nos dices: "no funciona". No me pronuncio sobre quién es más pro ni sobre el bien y el mal. Somos todos colegas acá, yo solamente soy más viejo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problema

Aparentemente alguna de las asignaciones a la variable dentro de otra asignación da problemas, por ejemplo en la línea

```
console.log(valor.innerText=0);
```

Estás asignando el valor 0 al **TEXTO** del contador, pero no estás modificando la variable.

A su vez, escribir esto:

```
valor.innerText=contador++;
```

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operadores_aritm%C3%A9ticos) de MDN (mencionado por Marcos en el comentario) cita lo siguiente:

> Operador unario. Agrega uno a su operando. Si se usa como operador
> prefijo (++x), devuelve el valor de su operando después de agregar
> uno; si se usa como operador sufijo (x++), devuelve el valor de su
> operando antes de agregar uno.

Probablemente (por el comportamiento, no estoy seguro a ciencia cierta ya que nunca escribo con esa sintaxis) primero asigna el valor a contador, y luego lo incrementa, por eso a veces necesitás hacer dos clics para ver el cambio.

Separando la modificación del contador de la renderización del valor, se resuelve el problema.

## Código

```js
    let botones=document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
    let valor=document.querySelector("#valor");
    let contador=0;
    
    for(let i=0; i<botones.length;i++){
        botones[i].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            if(botones[i].classList.contains("disminuir")){
                contador--;
            }else if(botones[i].classList.contains("incrementar")){
               contador++;
            }else{
                contador=0;
            }
            console.log(contador);
            valor.innerText=contador;
        })
    }
```

```html
<body> <main> <article id="contenedor_principal"> <h1>Contador</h1> <p id="valor">0</p> <div id="botones"> <button class="btn disminuir" type="button">Disminuir</button> <button class="btn resetear" type="button">Resetear</button> <button class="btn incrementar" type="button">Incrementar</button> </div> </article> </main> <script src="./contador.js"></script> </body>
```

Comment: Con respecto al operador `++` (incremento), no funciona igual que `x=x+1` [mas info acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operadores_aritm%C3%A9ticos)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! lo añadiré a la respuesta.

Comment: @Marcos ¿por qué si el operador unario retorna luego de incrementar, y luego las asignaciones compuestas se evalúan de derecha a izquierda, se tiene ese problema? Un poco de debug y se ve que primero asigna y luego incrementa.

Comment: Es que así se supone que debe funcionar, ese es el comportamiento esperado. Si te fijas en la documentación dice: _"Si x es 3, [...] mientras que x++ devuelve 3 y , solo entonces, establece x en 4."_. El uso normal es solo para incrementar (`x++;`). Se puede usar para asignar e incrementar pero se presta a error porque algunos no tienen en cuenta su comportamiento (_como ya vimos_)

Comment: Otra forma de verlo (_si se quiere_) sería `z = x++;` es quivalente a `(z = x), x += 1;`. Pensalo como asignar a `z` el valor actual de `x` y despues incrementar `x`

Comment: Es verdad, me había confundido porque había leído la definición para `++x`. Desde que dejé de usar C traté de evitar ese operador en todos los lenguajes, ja.